# What to do with NFS server (UTF-8) and Windows 7?

Tags: windows, nfs

NFS share is mounted using `mount server:/share x:` command.
File(cyrillic) "Новый текстовый документ.txt" created with samba share (and using UTF-8) is shown as "РќРѕРІС‹Р№ С‚РµРєСЃС‚РѕРІС‹Р№ РґРѕРєСѓРјРµРЅС‚.txt" under windows via NFS share.
How to make windows use UTF-8?

Comment: We have no clue what NFS client you're using.

Comment: it is a windows component.

Comment: I already saw that it has only 'ansi', some chineese encodings (How usefull). fu..ing windows!

Comment: As much as I hate Windows-bashing, lack of Unicode support is a good enough reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use fuse-convmvfs: mount your server folder by fuse-convmvfs (input charset - utf8, output - cp1251) and configure nfsd to use converted FS

example:

```
> convmvfs /mnt/converted-folder -o srcdir=/path/to/source/foleder, icharset=utf8,ocharset=cp1251

> vi /etc/exports
/mnt/converted-folder 192.168.1.*(rw,sync)
```

Comment: I'll mark it correct without testing and delete my useless answer

Answer (score 6):

## There is no solution with Microsoft's NFS client in Windows 7

There are no way to solve your problem under this setting, not even the method given in the "Correct Answer" of this question. This is not a mistake, it is by design to create the barrier you are facing. It is not possible that the designer of NFS Client offer the option to use BIG5, EUC-KR, EUC-JP, ksc5601, GB18030, SHIFT-JIS and simply *forget* UTF-8 and keep forgetting patching it up *in a decade*. All these codings are used by various versions of Windows except UTF-8, not a coincidence. In fact, Microsoft's intents to bridge old UNIX and Windows, to foster migration from Unix to Windows, and it must be carefully measured that this does not give its competitor Linux an easy environment to exist. Any feature makes Linux different from Unix or modern Unix different from old-unix-to-be-replaced are excluded. It's precision in marketing, job well done.

Let me show you how every way is blocked:

### To workaround the client side is no go:

Idea is to find some software that can dynamically transcode file names, for example by inserting itself a layer between FS and the OS. Or, find some software that can setup an environment for another software to use that file system. No known Windows software can do this. This does not work, because unlike Linux that allows each application to use a different encoding, Windows configure an encoding for a FILESYSTEM.

### To workaround the server is no go:

Most NFS servers are Linux. In theory one could use fuse-convmvfs to make a mirror of the filesystem and export that. Oleg Lobach demonstrated the code to do this, and it is marked correct without test. It doesn't work because Linux's NFS server can only export FUSE file system in NFSv4, not in NFSv2/v3, in the meantime, Windows 7 (as well as Services for Unix v3.5) only support NFSv2/v3, not NFSv4. I demonstrated [this limitation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102617/having-trouble-exporting-fuse-via-nfs/150727) in detail in another answer.

The problem is elaborated in [TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4dcbe190-1f27-410a-95fc-d1c9954b07bd/nfs-client-still-not-supporting-utf8-encoding):

> A POSIX filename is not ASCII but a stream of *bytes*.  The same goes for
> filenames on NFS filesystems.  The interpretation of the byte stream as a
> filename in a certain codeset is left as an exercise to the client
> application.  If the filename byte stream represents a valid UTF-8 string,
> but the client application has set the codeset to, say, ISO-8859-5, any
> problem is the fault of the application.
> But we're talking about Windows.  On Windows, the interpretation of a
> filename is not left to the application.  Rather, the filename byte stream
> sent from the NFS server to the Windows client machine has to be converted
> to a UTF-16 string to be digestible by the OS.  Therefore the interpretation
> of the filename byte stream has to be performed by the NFS client service,
> on a per mount point basis.  The application has no say in it.
> And here's the problem.  If the remote codeset used to create filenames is
> UTF-8, as is the default for many years in the POSIX world, there's no
> chance to get a correct filename from the Windows application point of view,
> because the interpretation of the filename is already done by the Windows
> NFS client which doesn't allow the conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16.  In
> fact, the NFS client only supports a restricted number of codeset
> conversions to UTF-16, all of them rather old-fashioned.
> This is not just a specific scenario.  You have this problem in all
> scenarios in which you're accessing NFS shares on machines set to use MBCS
> like UTF-8 or GB-18030 from Windows NFS clients.

## There are solutions if you opt for a switch:

The best solution is of course abandon Windows. It is not important nowadays, and the global trend is no longer to release Windows-only software. If you are stuck with old Windows applications, you can change your requirement:

- Switch NFSv2/v3 Client: you can install dokan user-land mount driver for Windows, then Neko NFS drive, which maps NFS to a device driver with an option "Unicode". Click that option to get UTF8 working. It supports NFSv2 and v3, but not v4. It doesn't support symbolic link yet (as Microsoft's client do).
- Switch NFSv4 Client: you can leave the in-built NFS Client for the [free reference implementation of NFS 4.1 for Windows by UMICH CITI](http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/windows/readme.html), although difficult to install, should either eliminate the problem (because NFS4 explicitly requires UTF-8) or made it possible to use workaround fuse-convmv mentioned above.
- Switch OS: Windows Server 2012 added support for NFS 4.1 server, so there is a chance that they included an NFS 4.1 client too.

Both switches would not work if your server only support NFSv3, for example, if you use OpenWRT (even the latest version of OpenWRT server still cannot do NFSv4).

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to note that I tried the UMICH CITI NFS client, but I ran into secure boot troubles.

Upon trying to run:

```
bcdedit /set testsigning on
```

as instructed by the instructions, I received the following error:

```
An error has occurred setting the element data.
The value is protected by Secure Boot policy and cannot be modified or deleted.
```

So unless you want to mess with your secure boot settings, I do not recommend trying to use the CITI client.

The optimal solution to this would be for CITI to sign the driver so it can be used without test mode. But considering it's quite old, I don't think this is going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

[machine translation from Russian]

If someone came here, like me, looking for a solution for shared folders over NFS under Windows 10, then the solution is in the region and system language settings. There is a section "Administrative language settings" where you can select UTF-8 as the system encoding [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqIts.png). This works for filenames in mounted network drives. In the picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uiemm.png) a whole partition with the Ext-4 file system is shared over NFS from Ubuntu (running in a virtual machine) and is natively mounted in Windows.

Если кто-то пришёл сюда также, как я, в поисках решения для общих папок через NFS под Windows 10, то решение есть в настройках региона и языка системы. Там есть раздел "Административные языковые параметры" где можно выбрать UTF-8 в качестве системной кодировки [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqIts.png). Это работает для имён файлов в примонтированных сетевых дисках. На снимке [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uiemm.png) целый раздел с файловой системой Ext-4 раздаётся по NFS из Ubuntu (запущенной в виртуальной машине) и примонтирован в Windows нативно.

Comment: This is a working solution, helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ответ от Alex Kart вполне рабочий, но, к сожалению, в Windows 10 и в Windows 11 поддержка UTF8 находится на уровне бета тестирования (забавно, но факт). Поэтому при монтировании каталогов в проводнике все будет видно в нужной кодировке, однако многие приложения этого по прежнему не поддерживают и будут сбоить при выводе. Так что пока вариант с бутербродом из fuse хоть и костылен, но оптимален.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).