# NFS mounted to drive fails with Hebrew file names

Tags: mount, nfs, character-encoding, hebrew

I have an NFS mounted to a drive on windows. 
With English filenames all is working as expected.

Whit Hebrew I get this error:

`“The file name(s) would be too long for the destination folder. You can shorten the file name and try again, or try a location that has a shorter path.”`

I use `ansi` in the Share premmisions of the nfs share. 
This is all the options I have:
`euc-jp|euc-tw|euc-kr|shift-jis|big5|ksc5601|gb2312-80|ansi`

And the mount command is:
`mount -o nolock,iocharset=utf8 \\10.10.10.110\test r:`

Comment: If the characters are multibyte, they may indeed be too long for the FS. Try entering a short Hebrew filename manually, if accepted on the NFS drive, then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229121/convert-unicode-utf-8-filenames-to-ansi-dos and https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/Filenameencodingandinteroperabilityproblems for converting multibyte-to-DOS filenames.

Comment: Hebrew characters are not ANSI and will not work. The best would be to convert the names to English, or set the NFS format to Unicode (perhaps UTF-8 will work, or if not then 16-bit Unicode).

Comment: @harrymc I tried that, didn't find a way. 
Can you point me to a solution.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/490369/8672) applies.

Comment: @harrymc It look good, but I don't see an option to install it on windows.
I will try it with cygwin - hope it will work.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I moved to SMB.