# nfs server on linux with windows 10 client

Tags: windows-10, raspberry-pi, nfs

I have a nfs server on a raspberry pi 3 b+, that share an ext4 directory.
The nfs client is a windows 10 computer.

I have a problem with filename characters encoding on client side. All accent characters are displayed badly (I am a french speaker, so some words have character like 'é' or 'è' for example).

My local setting on server side was en_US.UTF-8. I have changed it to fr_FR.UTF-8 but it change nothing.
It seems that nfs version used is nfs v3. But I didn't manage to force it to v4.
I have tried with a share directory on a ntfs partition, it's work fine and all wharacter well displayed.

Do you know what is the root cause of this type of problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do with NFS server (UTF-8) and Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/302407/what-to-do-with-nfs-server-utf-8-and-windows-7)